# Azure Function with KEDA Not scaling out

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-aks, keda

I am experimenting with Azure Function and Kubernetes with KEDA. i deployed my function to Kubernetes and its working fine.

But when i wanted to test out scaling , it says the following error

```
Name:                                    keda-hpa-techshare
Namespace:                               default
Labels:                                  <none>
Annotations:                             <none>
CreationTimestamp:                       Thu, 14 May 2020 12:51:56 +0530
Reference:                               Deployment/techshare
Metrics:                                 ( current / target )
  "queueLength" (target average value):  <unknown> / 5
Min replicas:                            1
Max replicas:                            100
Deployment pods:                         1 current / 0 desired
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason                   Message
  ----           ------  ------                   -------
  AbleToScale    True    SucceededGetScale        the HPA controller was able to get the target's current scale
  ScalingActive  False   FailedGetExternalMetric  the HPA was unable to compute the replica count: unable to get external metric default/queueLength/&LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{deploymentName: techshare,},MatchExpressions:[],}: unable to fetch metrics from external metrics API: the server could not find the requested resource (get 
queueLength.external.metrics.k8s.io)
Events:
  Type     Reason                        Age                     From                       Message
  ----     ------                        ----                    ----                       -------
  Warning  FailedGetExternalMetric       8m53s (x332 over 129m)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get external metric default/queueLength/&LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{deploymentName: techshare,},MatchExpressions:[],}: unable to fetch metrics from external metrics API: the server could not find the requested resource (get queueLength.external.metrics.k8s.io)
  Warning  FailedComputeMetricsReplicas  4m4s (x351 over 129m)   horizontal-pod-autoscaler  Invalid metrics (1 invalid out of 1), last error was: failed to get queueLength external metric: unable to get external metric default/queueLength/&LabelSelector{MatchLabels:map[string]string{deploymentName: techshare,},MatchExpressions:[],}: unable to fetch metrics from external metrics API: the server could not find the requested resource (get queueLength.external.metrics.k8s.io)
```

I have tried redeploying the image as well. Any help?

Comment: could you share the version of AKS you installed ? There was an issue with KEDA on 1.16.0 specifically  https://github.com/kedacore/keda/issues/515 with that metric.  Also could you run this command `k get --raw /apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/functions/queueLength`

Comment: This is on AKS , however i am not able to run the command

Comment: sure,, which version of Kunernetes are you Ising then ?

Comment: if the command fails, you might not have the external custom metrics installed/configured

Comment: I am using 1.15.10

Comment: What i meant was it says k is not recognized as a command , i am running in vscode

Comment: ah sorry `k` == `kubectl`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213879/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-djsly).